# Hex Timestamp to Human Readable Date

Tags: udp, timestamp, hex, decode, endianness

i am try to decipher a timestamp which is supposedly in DOS format. this timestamp is been passed over UDP as Binary Hex code. the approximate time this packet was captured was: "17:50:36 28/07/2014".

Hex bytes:

```
E806FD44
```

i have tried using RevEnge to check the Date Interpreters to see if anything is similar but nothing is close.. with very limited information on how this Hex is been passed i am finding this hard to decode into something readable.

the MS-DOS timestamp (32 bit swapped) with Hex "E806FD44" is decoding to:
"04/03/1980 00:00:00"

does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok great found it the decode format is "MS-DOS: 32 bit Hex Value".

for example, value to Decode:

```
36BFFD44
```

Date and Time decoded:

```
Tue, 29 July 2014 23:57:44  Local
```

now all i need to figure out is how to convert it! yikes!